# ASP.NET MVC - What is a use case of Url.Content()?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I cannot, for the life of me, think of any need for this function. MSDN says that it "Converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.". My question is, why are you using a relative path in the first place?

To illustrate, say you have a file at Scripts/awesome.js. You could get to this by doing

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/awesome.js")"></script>
```

But you could just as easily get to it using the path directly:

```
<script src="/Scripts/awesome.js"></script>
```

The same holds true for any images, CSS or any other static file you might need to reference. Can anyone show me a case where this function is needed?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answer. The reason I was looking at this is that when I try to do a rewrite to a path at a different depth, this is what breaks the most. See [ASP.NET MVC UrlHelper.GenerateUrl exception: "Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826299/asp-net-mvc-urlhelper-generateurl-exception-cannot-use-a-leading-to-exit-abo)

Comment: Content is a terrible name, I used to think it had something to do with the Content folder. It just does the same thing as ResolveUrl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your application is running as a sub app (running the site within a folder), you may have a path like `http://server.com/app/..`. In this case an absolute path to `/Scripts/...` will fail.

Comment: Thanks, I just found this out in a discussion with my peers. It does seem like it's overused though for applications that run on the root of a domain as opposed to in a virtual directory.