# When and how is RawUrl calculated?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, url-rewriting

Yes, I'm trying to change this value using IIS URL Rewrite, it's a long story and seems to be necessary: [ASP.NET MVC UrlHelper.GenerateUrl exception: "Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826299/asp-net-mvc-urlhelper-generateurl-exception-cannot-use-a-leading-to-exit-ab).

But the frustrating part is that it doesn't seem to respond to any request header assignments or server variable assignments by IIS URL Rewrite module... I can see that URL Rewrite is able to change request headers and server variables successfully, but RawUrl is still reflecting the original value. Begs the question, where the heck is it getting its value from?

[1] -
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/665/url-rewrite-module-20-configuration-reference#Allowed_Server_Variables_List

Comment: No, I believe we worked around the issue. Sorry.